# VBA Array issues

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to generate a random variable from 0-1 for 5000 times. And then, put them into ranges e.g. 0-0.05, 0.05-0.1.... so that I could count the frequency of each range.

However, it seems the code doesnt work. Anyone could help on it? Much appreciated!!!!

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub MNA()

    Dim Iteration As Long, i As Long

    Iteration = 5000

    ReDim AI1(Iteration) As Double

For i = 1 To Iteration:    Cells(4, 3) = i

    AI1(i) = RandomNumber

 Next i

Call Hist1(Iteration, 20, 0, 1, AI1)

End Sub

Function RandomNumber()

Randomize

RandomNumber = Rnd()

End Function
Sub Hist1(n As Variant, M As Long, Start As Double, Right As Double, arr() As Double)

   Dim i As Long, j As Long, Find As Long
   Dim Length As Double
   ReDim breaks(M) As Single
   ReDim freq(M) As Single


For i = 1 To M
    freq(i) = 0
Next i
    Length = (Right - Start) / M

For i = 1 To M
    breaks(i) = Start + Length * (i)
Next i

For i = 1 To n

    If (arr(i) <= breaks(1)) Then freq(1) = freq(1) + 1
    If (arr(i) >= breaks(M - 1)) Then freq(M) = freq(M) + 1

    For j = 2 To -1

        If (arr(i) > breaks(j - 1) And arr(i) <= breaks(j)) Then freq(j) = freq(j) + 1

    Next j
Next i

For i = 1 To M
    Cells(3, i + 13) = breaks(i)
    Cells(4, i + 13) = freq(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What is not working? You are not getting the correct output or you are getting an error?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am not getting the correct output.

Comment: What is the output you are getting and what is the output you are expecting?  Unfortunately, the SO crystal ball has been out of order so we need your input to know where the problem is

Comment: Rnd will only produce integers so only the values 0 and 1 will show in your sheet

Comment: `For j = 2 To -1` should be `For j = 2 To M-1`

Comment: @phil652, well, I thought in VBA, Rnd will generate a infinite number between 0-1 instead of 0,or 1. .......Do you have any clues on that?

Comment: Rnd doesn't do integers. Rnd "The Rnd function returns a value less than 1 but greater than or equal to zero." per the help file. Your array is populated with the expected values between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Rodger, agreed, I have tried to run it separately, and it does generate random values. Thanks.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct, Thanks, Yes, that was a typing mistake!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Just like arcadeprecinct said you had a typo. You also have to put `Call Hist1(Iteration, 20, 0, 1, AI1)` inside your loop.

Hope you can learn from this.

EDIT following Rodger's comment bellow

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub MNA()

    Dim Iteration As Long, i As Long

    Iteration = 5000

    ReDim AI1(Iteration) As Double

For i = 1 To Iteration:    Cells(4, 3) = i

    AI1(i) = RandomNumber
    Call Hist1(Iteration, 20, 0, 1, AI1)

 Next i



End Sub

Function RandomNumber()

Randomize

RandomNumber = Rnd


End Function
Sub Hist1(n As Variant, M As Long, Start As Double, Right As Double, arr() As Double)

   Dim i As Long, j As Long, Find As Long
   Dim Length As Double
   ReDim breaks(M) As Single
   ReDim freq(M) As Single


For i = 1 To M
    freq(i) = 0
Next i
    Length = (Right - Start) / M

For i = 1 To M
    breaks(i) = Start + Length * (i)
Next i

For i = 1 To n

    If (arr(i) <= breaks(1)) Then freq(1) = freq(1) + 1
    If (arr(i) > breaks(M - 1)) Then freq(M) = freq(M) + 1

    For j = 2 To M - 1

        If (arr(i) > breaks(j - 1) And arr(i) <= breaks(j)) Then freq(j) = freq(j) + 1

    Next j
Next i

For i = 1 To M
    Cells(3, i + 13) = breaks(i)
    Cells(4, i + 13) = freq(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Minor recommendation - If (arr(i) <= breaks(1)) Then freq(1) = freq(1) + 1
    If (arr(i) >= breaks(M - 1)) Then freq(M) = freq(M) + 1 .... shouldn't both have an equal. You could get a value that triggers then both. One should be <= and the other > or < and >=

Comment: I think VBA will do the logic step by step, once the value meet the first criteria, then, It wont execute the second step.

Comment: It will execute both unless you change the second one to an ELSEIF https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx

Comment: That works too. You will also need an "end if" on the following line. At the end of the day though, since you are dealing with 15 digits it probably won't ever come up... until that day it does and then you can't reproduce it and you are pulling out your hair trying to figure out what happened that time around compared to the 500 times it ran correctly. :-)